# change display style for link column type in content query webpart

Tags: 2013, web-part, query, content

I have some questions about content query web part with sharepoint 2013

I use the content query to filter a list.

This list has a column type link with some http links.

when I display it with the content query I got something like "http://XYZ.xxx, friendly name".

[image]

I would like to change that to friendly name only  with href to the http column value as a the link.

How can I achive that?

I already had a look into itemstyle template but not easy to deal with, just be able to find the bullet template i'm using but not able to change anything -(

any help could be usefull.

Many thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

- If it is a links list, you can use the notes field as display name

  **Link:** "URL [Custom Columns];"

  **Title:** "Notes;"

  **Description:** leave empty

  **Template:** Image on the Left
- If it is a custom list with a hyperlink field

  **Link:** Link_Field_Name

  **Title/Description:** leave empty

  **Template:** Image on the Left
- Create your own template

  You can add a new custom template to the list (dropdown) of available templates:

  1. Open Style Library/ItemStyle.xsl
  2. Paste the code below right above the "Default" template (instead of {$SafeLinkUrl}, which takes us to the display form, we will use the url from the field itself)
  3. Setup your webpart to use the new template

The code:

```
<xsl:template name="MyCustomTemplate" match="Row[@Style='MyCustomTemplate']" mode="itemstyle">
        <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
            <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
                <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
            <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
                <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="TheLink">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($DisplayTitle,',')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <div class="item link-item">
            <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>
            <a href="{$TheLink}" title="{@LinkToolTip}">
              <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams = 'True'">
                <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@OnClickForWebRendering"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams != 'True' and @OpenInNewWindow = 'True'">
                <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$OnClickTargetAttribute"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($DisplayTitle,',')"/>
            </a>
            <div class="description">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Description" />
            </div>
        </div>
</xsl:template>
```

The only relevant part is:

```
substring-after($DisplayTitle,',')
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I will try it, it's a custom list with a hyperlink type field. I would like to keep the bullets at the beginning. The next step will be adding a picture before the link friendly name. and finaly add a second field from the list being queried. step by step... -)

Comment: I tried to add the custom template into the  itemstyle go to the webpart properties but the new template is not there. anything the reload except the page containing the webpart?

Comment: a new item in the dropdown list should appear as soon as you add the template, save the file and refresh the page.

Comment: Hello, I tried the second change you proposed, It's not diplaying the right field anymore, I have to set the field in Title/description with the column name I want. will try again nwith the template.

Comment: try at least to get you template to appear in the list. edit the default itemstyle, save it, and refresh your page. should work

Comment: I have made some test by editing the itemstyle directly from the mapped drive to the web site, when in made modifications like this they are not taken into account. I  was wrong as I had to check out the itemstyle file first from the sharepoint style library and after do my changes from the map drive, finally check in, will let you know if it's working. thx

Comment: you do NOT want to change the file in the file system. it is an original file can can be overwritten by an MS update. all you need to do is edit the file in sharepoint designer which will become detached from the version on the file system. editing file system files requires iisreset, but again, you want to avoid that

Comment: ok will try it from sp designer, I'm new in sharepoint world, discovering each days -) , to be sure, I have to go to style library from sp designer and make updates from there ? I have read about creating a custom itemstyle file by editing the webpart exported definition to replace the itemstyle file path and re import the webpart.

Comment: you are right. however, editing the itemstyle directly is fine. you should try to play around with it and try to accomplish what you are looking for. in a later stage you can always revert the file to site definition and use your template in a separate file, but that is not something that you need to do. none of the approaches are a bad practice. keep it simple :)

Comment: Hello, you helped me a lot! It's now working! Thank you again!

Comment: The easiest way is the first option.  You set up the "Title" field in the list as the name you want the hyperlink to appear as.  Then you set up a "URL" hyperlink field:  enter the link in the address part, enter the same name you put in the Title field for the display name.  Then in the CQWP, in the "Presentation" section, "Link" gets `URL` and "Title" gets `Title [Custom Columns]`.  Couldn't be easier!  Saved me finding this answer!